# Why is there an "a" before a plural noun?

Tags: articles, definite-article, indefinite-article

In Washigton Post headline:

> "Watch Obama defend *a Trump supporter’s rights* at a Clinton 
>   rally"

Why is there an "a" before Trump supporter's rights ?

Is this because it is a special way to write  headlines or is there a grammar rule I miss here ?

Source: [www.washingtonpost.com](https://www.washingtonpost.com/news/inspired-life/wp/2016/11/04/watch-obama-defend-a-trump-supporters-rights-at-a-clinton-rally/)

Comment: The rights of ***a*** supporter of Trump.

Comment: Aha, I read it in different  way. Thank you so much  for your help Absolute.

Comment: @AbsoluteBeginner: Your comment would be better as an answer, as then the poster could accept it to show that this question has been answered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The **'a'** is there because the headline talks about one supporter - as Absolute Beginner commented, it's the rights of a supporter.

According to your comments, you understood it as the rights of *all* supporters of Trump, but the apostrophe shows that this interpretation can't be correct: in this case it would be "Trump **supporters'** rights" nstead of "a Trump **supporter's** rights".

Comment: Thank you Stephie, your comment adds another help. In fact what came to my mind was that the sentence is not talking about one specific supporter but in any supporter of Trump in general. So if I try to write the sentence to tells about any supporter,  what might be  the sentence ?  Could it be also as "Trump supporter's rights" ? (Whithou "a") I am not sure.

Comment: A specific supporter or a random one like in your original post?

Comment: I was thinking in a random one in my original post